# Populate textarea using buttons and entered text

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am working on a concept to be used on a tablet, where the user can enter text into a textarea via a series of shortcut buttons.  Of course the shortcut buttons don't cover all possibilities so I want to retain the ability to enter text normally into the text box.

The problem I have is that after the user applies focus to the textarea and makes plain text edits, the button cease to have any effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#keypad button").click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $("#Textarea").append(txt);
        });
});
```

```
<div id="keypad">
<div id="row4">
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Rt" value="Rt ">Rt</button>
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Lt" value="Lt ">Lt</button>
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Up" value="Up ">Up</button>
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Down" value="Down ">Down</button>
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Forward" value="Forward ">Forward</button>
    <button type="button" class="green45" name="Back" value="Back ">Back</button>
</div>
```

I have created this fiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/J228n/2/.  Start by entering some text using the buttons, then type some text in normally, then try to use the buttons again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#keypad button").click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#Textarea').val(function(i,val){
        return val + txt;
   });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEqVV/)

You need to use the `.val()` function, and return the old value + the text from the button.

Comment: Simples!  Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#keypad button").click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        var old =$("#Textarea").val();      
        $("#Textarea").val(old+txt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine:

```
$("#keypad button").click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $("#Textarea").val($("#Textarea").val()+txt);
});
```